# Changing icon place in MenuButton

Tags: qooxdoo

I'm having some troubles doing a very simple MenuButton. When I use a MenuButton the icon comes after the label (I mean right), instead of being left to it, as in qx.ui.form.Button.

Is there a simple way to put this icon in the right place ?

Comment: Could you show us what you have attempted so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MenuButton` inherits from `Button`, which has a property `iconPosition` - API docs [here](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/apiviewer/#qx.ui.form.Button). Just set it to wherever you want your icon to appear.

Comment: :-) As the saying goes, there's no such thing as a stupid question.